# how to align divs with different width within another parent div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This image will explain what I mean:

[image: What I want]

There is a transparent div that contains all the other small dark gray divs which has the dummy text in red ,

I set the parent div to

```
width:80%;
    height:100%;
    margin: auto;
    padding:0 0 0px;
```

and the child divs are not consistent in width their width change depending on the length of the text inside here is the CSS

```
float:left;
width:auto;
height:1.5em;
display: inline-block;
```

Now when new child divs are created they start perfectly aligned from the left hand side of the parent div, however on the right hand side they are not aligned at all to the end of the parent div (as in the image) they look messy. How to do that, is it possible with only CSS or Javascript will be needed ?

```
<div id="parent"><span class="child"></span></div>
```

Comment: You need to post your html as well if we need to help you :)

Comment: Also please edit the question and add that image as image hosting site is ban at my end. Thank you

Comment: Do you mean you want your text to be justified?

Comment: Tried that span part did not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from the Flex-box solution already mentioned you can simply use `text-align:justify` on the parent container like so:

```css
.container {
  background: #333;
  padding: 14px;
  font-size:0;
  text-align:justify;
}
.container div {
  display:inline-block;
  margin:4px;
  background: #111;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px;
  line-height: 1em;
  color: red;
  font-size:16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Maecenas faucibus</div>
  <div>mollis</div>
  <div>interdum</div>
  <div>Nullam</div>
  <div>id</div>
  <div>dolor</div>
  <div>id nibh ultricies</div>
  <div>vehicula</div>
  <div>ut</div>
  <div>id</div>
  <div>elit</div>
  <div>mollis</div>
  <div>interdum</div>
  <div>Nullam</div>
  <div>id</div>
  <div>dolor</div>
  <div>faucibus</div>
  <div>id nibh ultricies</div>
  <div>vehicula</div>
  <div>ut id</div>
  <div>elit</div>
  <div>dolor</div>
  <div>id nibh ultricies</div>
  <div>vehicula ut</div>
  <div>mollis</div>
  <div>interdum</div>
  <div>Nullam</div>
  <div>id</div>
  <div>dolor</div>
  <div>faucibus</div>
  <div>id nibh ultricies</div>
  <div>vehicula</div>
  <div>ut id elit</div>
</div>
```

Its worth noting that unlike flex-box's `justify-content: space-between` the `text-align:justify` property won't justify the final row.

Answer (score 2):

Although it's hard to tell what you might be asking, perhaps using you can use the flex layout?

On the parent div's CSS:

`display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
flex-wrap: wrap;`

You won't need the `float: left;` on the children.

Fiddle Sample: https://jsfiddle.net/c0nduj9r/